# How to create an Oracle date based on separate date and time components?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, datetime

How can you create an Oracle DATE variable based on a date from a DATE column and a fixed string?

Ie: Use to_date with the date coming from mytable.date_col and the string being fixed at "05:30"?

Comment: I used two methods in my answer to your last question *8-) What do you mean by 'variable' though - just a generated value to use within a query, or a PL/SQL variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert to a string and back, ignoring any existing time part:

```
to_date(to_char(date_col, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' 05:30:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

The `to_char()` gets just the date portion as a string, say `'2015-04-15'`. Your fixed time is then appended to that string, so it becomes `'2015-04-15 05:30:00'`. And that is then converted to a date, using a suitable matching format model.

Or take the date back to midnight using `trunc()` (assuming it may have a later time) and add the fraction of a day representing that time; which is 5.5 hours out of 24 hours so 5.5/24:

```
trunc(date_col) + 5.5/24
```

or the same thing with an interval:

```
trunc(date_col) + interval '0 05:30:00' day to second
```

Quick demo of all three:

```
with mytable (date_col) as (
  select to_date('2016-04-15 15:16:17', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual
)
select to_date(to_char(date_col, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' 05:30:00',
    'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as res1,
  trunc(date_col) + 5.5/24 as res2,
  trunc(date_col) + interval '0 05:30:00' day to second as res3
from mytable;

RES1                RES2                RES3              
------------------- ------------------- -------------------
2016-04-15 05:30:00 2016-04-15 05:30:00 2016-04-15 05:30:00
```